# Material UI v4 Typography: redundant CSS rules overriding my custom theme

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, typography

In my Material UI theme, I've defined the styles for each variant:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
        primary: {
            main: "#1dc0d7",
        },
        secondary: {
            main: "#c9c9c9",
            dark: "#505255",
        },
    },
    typography: {
        allVariants: {
            color: "#505255",
        },
        body1: {
            fontSize: '1em',
        },
        body2: {
            lineHeight: 1.25,
        },
        subtitle2: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        h1: {
            fontSize: '2.4em',
        },
        h6: {
            fontSize: '1.25em',
        },
    },
});
```

However, for some odd reason, my "h1" variant CSS rule is being overridden by another rule, and I have no idea where it comes from:

[image: Screenshot]

Any ideas?

Comment: could be many reasons. have you set the ThemeProvider properly? 
ref: https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-provider

then check how you have set the styles to components. your component might be overriding the styles.
ref: https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#overriding-styles-classes-prop

Comment: Thanks @MrClemRkz, I'll take a look

Comment: sure. can help out easily if you share the part of the code which reproduces the same problem you find, via https://codesandbox.io/.